# Function name or Variable

Tags: javascript

I am using functions in my code and i am asking what is the best way to use them?

```
// is the function name square a variable?
function square(number) {
  return number**2;
}
var output=square(5);
console.log(output);
```

I am just wondering  this code prints out the same results. My question is `square` a global variable or just a function name?

Comment: its a function name within the current execution context

Answer (score 1):

As you declare square as function `function square(number)` it is now a function.

So therefore when you declared the variable output `var output=square(5);` you give it the value which was returned by the method inside of `square()` function.